# Url rewriting : prevent to display xml

Tags: xml, security, mod-rewrite, header

**Edit** :
I've got an aspx file (default.aspx) that loads a flash file (index.swf), but this swf needs a xml file (foo.xml) to load correctly. However, I would like to block any request aiming directly at the xml file.

Is it possible, using a rewritting engine (isapi_rewrite for example) to detect if the xml file is being 'hotlinked' or being loaded by the 'index.swf'(inside default.aspx)?

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can examine the http referer with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ...` but remember that some proxies and browsers have this turned off so you'll always get a blank referer.

Comment: Let's say that it can be (;)), how would I do this?